# Diferencia de horas exactas entre Fecha A y Fecha B

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
$qry = "select 

                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada, 
                CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)/60.0 as decimal (18,2) ) %24 AS sumaHoras 
            from tblasistencia where idclave = '".$empno."' and 
                fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 00:00:00',103) and 
                CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 23:59:59',103)";
```

Còmo puedo mejorar la consulta, para que al hacer la suma de horas con la funciòn DATEDIFF
me devuelva màs exacto los cálculos, es decir quiero hacer mas amigable para el usuario, la lectura de los datos.

```
Caso 1
21:00:50    06:02:51    9.03
```

Multiplicar 0.03 * 60 para que salga los 1.8 minutos a parte,
es decir 9 hras y 1.8 minutos.

Resultado actual

```
 Hora A      Hora B     Suma
21:00:50    06:02:51    9.03
21:09:40    06:26:16    9.28
21:12:06    07:22:12    10.17
21:16:45    06:26:16    9.17
21:27:36    06:02:40    8.58
21:21:10    06:09:49    8.8
21:12:13    06:09:48    8.95
21:08:34    06:02:32    8.9
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con un valor más exacto?

Comment: el cálculo de los minutos màs aproximado

Comment: Ok, tomemos de ejemplo el primer caso `9.03` que son 9 horas  y `0.03` de una hora, es decir `1.8` minutos. ¿Como lo quisieras ver?

Comment: Exacto, quiero hacer mas amigable para el usuario, la lectura de los datos, o de alguna forma multiplicar 0.03 * 60 para que salga los 1.8 minutos a parte es decir 9 hras y 1.8 minutos

Comment: Te entiendo, obviamente perderías la condición numérica de la columna. Dejame ver, creo que ya hay una respuesta por esto, sino armamos una.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma general de resolverlo es calculando la diferencia en una magnitud mínima, por ejemplo en segundos, y básicamente lo que haremos es:

1. El cociente de los segundos divididos 86400 son los días (Un día tiene 86400 seg.)
2. El cociente del resto de (1) dividido 3600 serán las horas
3. El cociente del resto de (2) dividido 60 serán los minutos
4. El resto final serán los segundos

Conceptualmente sería algo así:

```
DECLARE @Diff       INT
DECLARE @From       DATETIME
DECLARE @To         DATETIME

SELECT  @From   = '1900-01-01 21:00:50'
SELECT  @To     = '1900-01-02 06:02:51'
SELECT  @Diff   = DATEDIFF(SECOND,@From,@To)

select  convert(varchar(10), (@Diff/86400)) + ':' +                        -- dia
        convert(varchar(10), ((@Diff%86400)/3600)) + ':'+                  -- hora
        convert(varchar(10), (((@Diff%86400)%3600)/60)) + ':'+             -- min
        convert(varchar(10), (((@Diff%86400)%3600)%60)) as 'DD:HH:MM:SS'   -- seg
```

Salida (9 horas dos minutos 1 segundo):

```
DD:HH:MM:SS
0:9:2:1
```

Resuelto en tu consulta:

```
select  convert(varchar(10), (DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)/86400)) + ':' +                        -- dia
        convert(varchar(10), ((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)/3600)) + ':'+                  -- hora
        convert(varchar(10), (((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)%3600)/60)) + ':'+             -- min
        convert(varchar(10), (((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)%3600)%60)) as 'DD:HH:MM:SS'   -- seg
        from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de utilizar `(DATEDIFF(minute, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)` utiliza `(DATEDIFF(time, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)` porque lo que quiere obtener es el la hora exacta con sus minutos y segundos, no tienes porque convertirlos a decimal conviertelos a tipo `TIME`